# How I can control HDMI to what content should visible on projector screen?

Tags: hdmi

I was presenting slides in classroom, I found that only full screen content are visible in projector. I was not able to present anything which was not set on full screen mode.
How I can control what to show in projector screen? Is there any presentation modes ? Please suggest GUI or terminal based application for it.

[image]

Comment: added details, it's x11 session, os ubunut 22.04 lts

Comment: ok thank you for insights, I'm not that much geek, I hope you got my problem !